# OpenGL - drawing like in nehe tutorial

Tags: android, opengl-es

I used to make simple games for PC in OpenGL, now I want to do something on Android.
But, much things is different... Why drawing square is so complicated? (http://www.jayway.com/2009/12/04/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android--part-ii-building-a-polygon/)
Why it isn't as simple as in nehe tutorials:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                      // Drawing Using Triangles
glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top
glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Left
glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Right
glEnd();                            // Finished Drawing The Triangle
```

Is there any way to use OpenGL like in nehe tutorials?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to draw in OpenGL ES 2 right?  OpenGL ES 2 requires you to use shaders, which are a lot more work, but better for the long term.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, no, the old style pipeline is gone.

Out with the fixed-function, immediate mode, matrix hierarchies etc., and in with shaders and buffers.

Answer (score 2):

> Why it isn't as simple as in nehe tutorials:

Because using the immediate mode is not simple. What makes the immediate mode so appealing is, that you can throw in your numbers directly into the function calls. *What if* you'd were to load your geometry from a file? You most likely will! Then your geometry is in some buffer. Then you need to build loops, call immediate mode functions in the right order, etc. etc. Once you've got your geometry in a buffer, it's actually easier to just point OpenGL to it and issue a handfull of glDrawElement or glDrawArray calls.

Does using vertex arrays look complicated on first sight? Yes. But in the long run vertex arrays are much, much easier to use.

Also they're far more efficient, because you can send large amounts of geometry in batches.

> Is there any way to use OpenGL like in nehe tutorials?

You're targeting OpenGL-ES and no, it's not possible (also not with OpenGL-3 core and later). And frankly: You shouldn't do it the NeHe style in the first place. The NeHe tutorials are outdated and don't make efficient use of modern GPU capabilities.

Comment: Also there is quite a difference in performance, when calling thousands of methods, compared to one, for bigger geometry.